# Custom BaseAdapter or CursorAdapter or CursorLoader?

Tags: android

I have 2 fragment:

```
Fragment A: Here user enters some data and it is stored in database.   
Fragment B: Here the entered data is loaded from the database in a listview in its onResume lifecycle method.
```

Now, the problem I am having is that every time a data is added and Fragment B is opened, the entire `listview` is reloaded. I just want to load only the row which was added into the `listview`.
Currently I am using custom `BaseApadter`. No `cursoradapter` or `cursorloader`!

Comment: your data model is sql db based, so the natural solution is [Simple]CursorAdapter

Comment: yup, this is the most simple solution i find. using cursor loaders to load 4-5 rows is too much worksome. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that don't use **setAdapter()** everytime your data changes. i.e:

create a method that refresh the data in your adapter

```
class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public void refreshData(String[] arrayData) {
            this.arrayData = arrayData;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

check if the adapter already set in your activity

```
       if (listView.getAdapter() == null) {
            adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), data);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       } else
            adapter.refreshData(data);
```

Comment: I am still not getting the result. I put a Log below the listView.setAdapter(adapter) code saying adapter was null and so it was set for the first time. And everytime this log is being show which means that adapter is still being set everytime.

Comment: what am i supposed to repace "data" with? I have an ArrayList<singleRow> named todoItems. I replace it with todoItems.

Comment: replace it with whatever that fill the listview. if you are creating new instance for your fragment everytime you open it naturally everthing in your fragment is going to be null

Comment: i suggest you to save your fragment instance when you open it once or save your data when loaded once and retrieve your fragment from this instance everytime its open

Answer (score 0):

E believe your question should be Custom `BaseAdapter` or `CursorAdapter` with a `CursorLoader` i will explain why,

A `CursorAdapter` is used for loading and presenting data originating from a `ContentProvider`
basically you initialise it with the query and and on the `Adapter` implementation you bind the cursor data with the `ListView` item views, a `CursorAdapter` "wraps" a cursor, which you can use to listen to data changes using a `ContentObserver` the android framework provides `CursorLoader` class to assist with the task of listening for data changes  by abstracting you from the trouble with using `ContentObservers` and also by proving the loading of data in an asynchronous fashion, handling cases such as data changed, cursor is in the process of querying for new data, but meanwhile data changed again etc.

To anwnser your question and seeing that you want the Fragment to reflect changes to the underlying data i would advise using a `CursorAdapter` with a `CursorLoader`

Heres the guide on using a `CursorLoader` https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Comment: ok, i understand this now. I want to ask u one more thing. Actually my list view will be having hardly 5-6 rows. So shall i use cursor loader or simple cursor adapter?

Comment: It depends, if you want the list to reflect data changes i would go with the cursor loader, its a few lines of code and pays off